# LabVIEW Report Generation returns error code (-2147319779) when downgraded from MS Office 365 to Office 2013

Tags: ms-office, labview, office-2013

I am using LabVIEW 2018 32 bit version. In our LabVIEW application, we use Excel Report Generation functions. It was developed with Office 365 installed. Now I want to use Office 2013 for the Report Generation instead of O365.

The report generated fine with Office 365. I downgraded my system to Office 2013 and re-linked the invoke nodes. But, while generating report, it returns the following error:

> **Error -2147319779 occurred at Library not registered.  in NI_Excel.lvclass:new report subVI.vi->NI_report.lvclass:Create Report.vi**
>
> **This error code is undefined. Undefined errors might occur for a number of reasons. For example, no one has provided a description for the code, or you might have wired a number that is not an error code to the error code input.**
>
> **Additionally, undefined error codes might occur because the error relates to a third-party object, such as the operating system or ActiveX. For these third-party errors, you might be able to obtain a description of the error by searching the Web for the error code (-2147319779) or for its hexadecimal representation (0x8002801D).**

I searched for the error code and understood that it is because the library files are not registered. I tried re-registering those dlls, but with no success.

Can anyone please suggest how I can resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you un-install and re-install the report generation toolkit after the change in Office version? That's what I've had to do when I get a new version of Office